# no puedo conectar NODE.JS a SQL SERVER a traves de MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, mssql

No llevo camino de conectar node a SQL-Server; hace 3 días que estoy intentando con todo tutorial que encuentro en YT/Google y siempre obtengo el mismo error. El código que uso es este (usé muchísimos otros mas también):

```
const sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
user: 'sa',
password: '1234',
server: 'localhost', 
database: 'ElectroBroker' 
};


var mssql = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
mssql.connect().then(function(){
var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
req.query("SELECT * from Embarque").then(function(res){
    console.table(res);
});
}).catch(function(err){
console.log(err);
});
```

- Tengo habilitado SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode
- Tengo habilitado TCP/IP con los ipadress: tcp Dynamic ports todos en blanco, IP9 a 127.0.0.1 y IPAII TCP Dynamic a 49675 y TCP Port a 1433
- Tengo corriendo los servicios SQL Server y SQL Server Browser (SQL Server Agent no lo puedo arrancar pero no se si se usa)
- He probado conectarme desde sql server al 127.0.0.1 y si puedo

El mensaje que siempre obtengo en la consola es:

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate
    at E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:65:17
    at Connection.onConnect (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1020:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:483:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Connection.emit (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1048:18)
    at Connection.socketError (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1641:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connecti    at Socket.emit (events.js:388:22)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate
      at ConnectionError (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.socketError (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1641:56)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1405:14)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:388:22)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {      
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  }
}
PS E:\Proyectos\node-sql> node app.js
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate
    at E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:65:17
    at Connection.onConnect (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1020:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:483:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Connection.emit (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1048:18)
    at Connection.socketError (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1641:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1405:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:388:22)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate
      at ConnectionError (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)
      at Connection.socketError (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1641:56)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Proyectos\node-sql\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1405:14)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:388:22)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
      at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {      
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  }
}
```

Comment: por favor, solo era eso?? muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error es bastante claro:

El problema es que tu aplicación está requiriendo una conexión encriptada y no está aceptando el certificado del servidor, que es auto-firmado.

Puedes cambiar las propiedades de tu conexión, por ejemplo, agregar el parámetro `trustServerCertificate: true`:

Por ejemplo:

```
var config = {
user: 'sa',
password: '1234',
server: 'localhost', 
database: 'ElectroBroker',
options: { 
  trustServerCertificate: true,
  } 
};
```

Eso debiera corregir el problema de conexión que estás enfrentando.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @Trauma, he corregido el código de la respuesta, gracias por el comentario!

Comment: Es bastante claro cuando entiendes de certificados y demas, jaja. Llevo 3 dias con node y el mundo del back apenas. Muchas gracias!!